# IntelliJ Throws error fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository. Trying to install a module with go get

Tags: git, go, intellij-idea, prometheus, readline

I am trying to install [Prometheus][1] on my GO project using the following command inside my intelliJ terminal:

```
go get github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus
```

and when I do so I am getting the following error:

```
GOROOT=/usr/lib/golang #gosetup
GOPATH=/home/yakiza #gosetup
/usr/lib/golang/bin/go list -modfile=/home/yakiza/IdeaProjects/Zephyros/go.mod -m -json -mod=mod all #gosetup
go: github.com/prometheus/client_golang@v1.12.2 requires
    github.com/prometheus/common@v0.32.1 requires
    golang.org/x/oauth2@v0.0.0-20210514164344-f6687ab2804c requires
    cloud.google.com/go@v0.65.0 requires
    github.com/google/pprof@v0.0.0-20200708004538-1a94d8640e99 requires
    github.com/chzyer/readline@v0.0.0-20180603132655-2972be24d48e: invalid version: git fetch -f origin refs/heads/*:refs/heads/* refs/tags/*:refs/tags/* in /home/yakiza/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/2b1d73c01d25b37519a4c8fa4a9da66549ac9cb349c7eed83e8fc258c189ca92: exit status 128:
    fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
    
    Please make sure you have the correct access rights
    and the repository exists.
```

I noticed that if I go ahead and try to install the module using the the terminal ( not inside the IDE) everything gets installed properly, but when I open the project with the IDE the error still stands and I cannot run my project successfully.

I tried to delete the packages from the project, with no success. Additionally tried to install the module on another project using IntelliJ same issue.
[1]: https://prometheus.io/docs/guides/go-application/

Comment: IntelliJ has probably exported some `GIT_*` environment variables (e.g., `GIT_DIR`), thus breaking direct use of Git for other purposes (although Go has its own implementation of Git so it might be something else).

Comment: Just checked the environment variables nothing of that sort as far as I can see.

Answer (score 1):

I looked everywhere to try and find a solution for this, but unfortunately I was not able to find the root cause of this.

I can say for certain that is something within IntelliJ causing this, and the reason for that I [restored the IDE settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-project-and-ide-settings.html#back-up-restore)

From the main menu, select File | Manage IDE Settings | Restore Default Settings.

Then restarted my IDE and everything works as expected